# Rails undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass - form collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My controller:

```
def new
  @campaigns = current_user.business.campaigns

  # Calling @campaigns from the controller and view (using the byebug gem) shows:
  # #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Campaign id: 1, title: "My Campaign">]>

  # So it IS getting loaded in the controller and view.
end
```

My form:

```
<%= f.collection_select :campaign_id, @campaigns, :id, :title %>
```

The campaigns *are showing* in the select box as they should.

The error I get when I submit the form (on the line shown above from my form):

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

However, the error doesn't occur if  I change my `collection_select` to this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :campaign_id, Campaign.all, :id, :title %>
<!-- Notice the "Campaign.all" above -->
```

As for my models: `user` has one `business` has_many `campaigns` through `(irrelevant model)`

What am I missing? Is it because it's returning a `CollectionProxy`?

Comment: @campaigns is probably going to be nil in the view, for whatever reason. Maybe the view code is inside a partial that doesn't get passed the parameter :campaigns?

Comment: @Pyro excellent thought! However, the campaigns do show in the select box as they should, so they are getting passed into the view correctly.

Comment: Wow, I figured it out and it was so simple. I hadn't defined `@campaigns` in the `create` action, therefore, when I submitted the form, it was `nil`. Not enough black coffee today I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I had not set the `@campaigns` instance variable inside of my `create` action. This is why the select box looked fine but gave an error on submit. Obviously! After adding the `@campaigns` to my `create` action, the problem went away.

Additionally, I needed to add the same line to my `edit` and `update` actions, so I created a `before_action` to keep it DRY.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_select_collections, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :create]

  private
    def set_select_collections
      @campaigns = current_user.business.campaigns
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be happening because while you are correctly creating the `@campaigns` object in the `new` method, you then post to another method (most likely `create`) which renders the page again (presumably redirects to `edit` or renders `new`) but in that method **you aren't re-creating the `@campaigns` object**, and it is therefore not available to the view.

Add `@campaigns = current_user.business.campaigns` to your create method, or to your edit method, or to both.

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to get it already. I posted the solution as a comment to my original question. I guess I should answer my own question